# Simultaneously applying same modification to all ggarrange subplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, ggpubr

I am in the process of finalising some ggplot figures for a journal with strict graphics requirements.
For example, I have to make sure that the text size is smaller than 7pt, and I defined the following variable, which I can add to any ggplot:
`reqs <- theme(axis.text = element_text(size=5, family='sans'), text=element_text(size=7,family='sans'))`

I was thinking of generalising this one step further, by writing a `ggsave_reqs`  function which applies the required changes to simple ggplots or ggarrange objects.
According to `?ggarrange`, elements from this class are either ggplots or lists of ggplots, and so I tried automatising "suplot changes' with:
`lapply(ggarr, function(gg) gg + reqs )`
However, this does not work, and I get the bug:

" Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?"

Does anyone have any ideas on whether automatising these ggarrange subplot modifications is possible?

A minimal working example is as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

df <- data.frame(X=runif(1000, 0,1),
                 Y=runif(1000, 2,3),
                 CLASS=as.factor(rbinom(1000, size=1, p=.5)))

.g <- function(DF)
{
    ggplot(DF, aes(x=X, y=Y,color=CLASS)) +
    geom_point()
}

ggarr <- ggarrange( .g(df), .g(df[1:10,]))
reqs <- theme(legend.position='bottom') 

# none of these works
ggarr + reqs
lapply(ggarr, function(p){ p + reqs } )

# however this works
ggarr <- ggarrange( .g(df) + reqs, .g(df[1:10,]) + reqs)
```

Comment: Your `ggarr` is a ggplot object. And a ggplot object is basically a list with elements like `data`, `layers` or `scales`. When using `lapply` you are looping over these elements and "add" your `theme` adjustments to each of these elements which for the third element (=`scales`) results in an error. Instead I would suggest to put your plots in a list. Then use lapply to add ´reqs`. Then pass the resulting list to ggarrange.

Comment: Thank you for the comment stefan. I will implement what you said, but it would be great to know whether subplots can be modified after the application of ggarrange.

Comment: Don't think that this is possible. Or even if it requires a lot of effort, which IMHO is not worth it. Perhaps one more reason to switch to `patchwork` which is my go to guy for such tasks: `library(patchwork); patch <- .g(df) + .g(df[1:10,]); patch & reqs`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I came across patchwork looking for answers online but I never tried it. I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this solution with `dplyr`. Just apply this change to the list of plots before `ggarrange`, not after

```
library(dplyr)
lapply(list(.g(df), .g(df[1:10,])), function(x){x + reps}) %>% 
  ggarrange(plotlist = .)
```

I cannot comment so I will reply here.

The important thing is to apply the themes or other changes to a list of plots, but not plot after `ggarrange`. And yes, there is no need for `dplyr`

So this works.

```
p <- list(.g(df), .g(df[1:10,]))
newp <- lapply(p, function(x){x + reps})
ggarrange(plotlist = newp)
```

But this does not work.

```
p <- ggarrange(.g(df), .g(df[1:10,]))
lapply(p, function(x){x + reps})
```

Comment: Sorry but 1. this doesn't answer the question nor add any more knowledge than reported by the comments and 2. there is no need for the dplyr package in this snippet.